# prevent vuex from update when filling the input form

Tags: vuex

In my Vuex app, I have an update form that populates the input fields with the user's profile (from the Vuex store), then on submission submits the form to the database.

So I need to display the user's profile on the page, but don't want them to be updated (reactively) when the users are changing the values in the form, as in my case it's misleading if the user does not complete the form leaves the page and comes back to it. Then it may look like the data has been updated (which it hasn't as they are yet to submit the form).

**Template vue**

```
<div class="d-block mb-5">
            <label for="profile-description" class="mb-2">{{
              $t('setting.change_profile.self_introduction')
            }}</label>
            <textarea
              v-model="profile.self_introduction"
              class="w-100 resize-none border px-3 py-2"
              rows="8"
              id="profile-description"
            ></textarea>
          </div>
```

**Typescript file**

```
public profile: any = {
    email_option: 1,
    avatar: '',
    last_name: '',
    first_name: '',
    last_name_kana: '',
    first_name_kana: '',
    self_introduction: ''
  }

  created() {
    this.getUserProfile()
  }

  getUserProfile() {
    UserService.getUserProfile()
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          this.profile = res.data
          UserModule.HANDLE_USER_PROFILE(this.profile)
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  updateProfile() {
    this.$refs.observer.validate().then(isValidate => {
      if (!isValidate) {
        return
      } else {
        const new_profile = {
          email_option: this.profile.email_option,
          avatar: this.profile.avatar,
          last_name: this.profile.last_name,
          first_name: this.profile.first_name,
          last_name_kana: this.profile.last_name_kana,
          first_name_kana: this.profile.first_name_kana,
          self_introduction: this.profile.self_introduction
        }
        UserService.updateUserProfile(new_profile)
          .then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
              let user_name = `${this.profile.first_name} ${this.profile.last_name}`
              UserModule.UPDATE_USER_NAME(user_name)
              this.$bvModal.show('modal-success')
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            this.getUserProfile()
            this.$bvModal.show('modal-error')
          })
      }
    })
  }
```

Vuex store

```
profile: {
      email: '',
      email_option: 1,
      avatar: require('@/assets/images/user-avatar.png'),
      last_name: '',
      first_name: '',
      last_name_kana: '',
      first_name_kana: '',
      self_introduction: ''
    },
@Mutation
  handleUserProfile(user_profile: any) {
    this.user.profile = user_profile
  }

  @Action({ rawError: true })
  HANDLE_USER_PROFILE(user_profile: any) {
    this.context.commit('handleUserProfile', user_profile)
  }
```

Comment: Would be nice to mark my answer as the accepted answer. Thank you and see you on the next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `v-model="profile.self_introduction"` in your `Template.vue`. As `profile.self_introduction` directly affects the state in the store, you may also come across the following error:

```
Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
```

To solve this, you need to set up a v-model with no reference to your store states and dispatch this one to the store after submit.

If you need to prefill you form with data from the store, you need to work around the easy way of just applying the data to a new object. For example:

```
this.localToFillForm = this.objectFromStore;
```

If you would use `this.localToFillForm` to prefill a form and also use it as the v-model for this form, it still relates to `this.objectFromStore`.

A simple trick is to just create a new object:

```
this.localToFillForm = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.objectFromStore));
```

In this case, `this.localToFillForm` wont relate to `this.objectFromStore` anymore.

Comment: Can you help me with this case? I tried by set profile = store.state.objectfromvuex but it doesn't seem to work very well

Comment: @thinh6699 Would be good to see more information to this new problem. If it´s related to this topic, just edit your answer. If it´s not related, please insert a new question and I will try to help you there. If my answer here helped you with this case it would be nice, if you mark is as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try to fix it by myself first. It would be nice if you could help after that

Comment: @thinh6699 Sure. Just ask the question under the `vue.js` tag and I will help you.